# Doble referencia a una tabla MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una base de datos en la cual se almacenan los datos de estudiantes que han pasado del bachillerato a la universidad, ahora bien el centro educativo tiene 5 sedes y se da el caso que jovenes que estudiaron en una sede, actualmente se esten reportando o asistiendo a las capacitaciones a otra sede.

Mi lio es el siguiente:

[image: Esta es la estructura de la tabla estudiante]

Esta es la estructura de la tabla estudiante.

[image: Esta es la estructura de la tabla de sedes]

Esta es la estructura de la tabla de sedes.

En la tabla de estudiantes existe un campo `headquarter` donde se almacena una FK referente a la sede donde estudio el alumno, además de esto, necesito un campo donde se refiera a la sede donde este asiste a las capacitaciones pero esto me crea una doble referencia a la misma tabla.

¿me podrían ayudar con una solución para esto?

Comment: Yo aplicaría esta solución: crear una nueva tabla que maneje las relaciones que planteas. Vamos a llamarla `student_headquarter`, con las columnas `carnet,  id_headquarter, type` en la tabla `student` ya no habría columna para headquarters (la relación se traslada a la nueva tabla) , la columna `type` serviría para saber si el estudiante estudia o se capacita en ese h.q. , habrá una fila por cada situación y el modelo permitiría que un estudiante estudie o se capacite en varios hq en años o periodos distintos. Si te interesa puedo proponer un ejemplo.

Comment: Creo que te entendí bien pero pon el ejemplo por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es el modelo de datos al que me refería en mi comentario.  Lo explico brevemente:

- Hemos sacado de la tabla `student` la columna `headquarter`, trasladándola a una nueva tabla que manejará las relaciones `student` -> `headquarter`
- Hemos creado una tabla `student_headquarter` capaz de manejar una relación muchos a muchos entre `student` y `headquarter`. Eso significa que en el modelo de datos un estudiante puede **durante todos los años como estudiante** estar inscrito en varias sedes (por cada inscripción en una sede habrá una fila con el carnet del estudiante y el id de la sede).  Conviene detenerse un poco sobre esta tabla:

  - tiene una columna `type` que serviría para identificar qué tipo de inscripción tiene el estudiante en esa sede. Por ejemplo, `type 1` sería una inscripción como estudiante, `type 2` sería una capacitación, `type n`  sería lo que sea. Nótese que si los `type` son muchos habría que extender el modelo, creando también una tabla `type`...
  - esta tabla está pensada incluso para futuras evoluciones del modelo de datos. Imaginemos que las cosas cambian y un estudiante puede estar inscrito en una sede en un determinado período y en otra sede en otro período distinto. Ese cambio sería manejado agregando una nueva columna `periodo` a la tabla y listo. Habría que cambiar la restricción de unicidad y ya, nuestro modelo está listo para manejar la nueva situación sin ningún trauma.

Dicho esto, te dejo un ejemplo basado en datos reales. A continuación todo el código de creación de tablas e inserción de datos de prueba:

```
/*MYSQL: Estudiantes y centros tabla asociativa - https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/185957/29967*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student 
(
    student_id       INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    carnet           VARCHAR(12),
    student_name     VARCHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT student_AK01 UNIQUE (carnet)
)ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS headquarter 
(
    hq_id         INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    headquarter   VARCHAR(150),
    CONSTRAINT headquarter_AK01 UNIQUE (headquarter)
 )ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student_headquarter 
(
    carnet          VARCHAR(12),
    hq_id           INT,
    type            TINYINT,
    CONSTRAINT student_headquarter_PK PRIMARY KEY (carnet,hq_id,type),
    FOREIGN KEY (carnet) REFERENCES student(carnet) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE  CASCADE, 
    FOREIGN KEY (hq_id) REFERENCES headquarter(hq_id) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE  CASCADE            
)ENGINE=INNODB;


INSERT INTO student (student_name, carnet) 
    VALUES
    ('Pedro', 'P-01'),
    ('Santiago', 'S-01'),
    ('Juan', 'J-01') ;


INSERT INTO headquarter (headquarter) 
    VALUES
    ('Sede 1'),
    ('Sede 2'),
    ('Sede 3'),
    ('Sede 4'),
    ('Sede 5');

INSERT INTO student_headquarter (carnet,hq_id,type) 
    VALUES
    ('P-01',1,1),
    ('P-01',5,2),
    ('S-01',2,1),
    ('S-01',3,2),
    ('J-01',4,1),
    ('J-01',1,2),
    ('P-01',2,2);
```

---

Vamos ahora a probar con una consulta como esta:

```
SELECT 
    s.carnet, 
    s.student_name, 
    h.headquarter, 
    sh.type 
FROM student_headquarter sh
    INNER JOIN student s  ON sh.carnet=s.carnet
    INNER JOIN headquarter h ON sh.hq_id=h.hq_id;
```

**Resultado:**

```
carnet  student_name    headquarter        type
---------------------------------------------------
P-01    Pedro           Sede 1              1
P-01    Pedro           Sede 2              2
P-01    Pedro           Sede 5              2
S-01    Santiago        Sede 2              1
S-01    Santiago        Sede 3              2
J-01    Juan            Sede 1              2
J-01    Juan            Sede 4              1
```

¿Qué muestra el resultado? Si tomamos el caso de `Pedro`, vemos que el estudiante está inscrito en la `Sede 1` en un tipo `1` (estudiante)  y que ha hecho capacitación (`type 2`)  en `Sede 2` y en `Sede 5`.

Debo decir también que este modelo te permitirá hacer con suma facilidad cosas que de otro modo serían muy complicadas, como agrupar datos por cualquiera de las columnas implicadas, hacer cálculos, etc.

---

#### Demostración

Aquí puedes ver una <kbd>**[DEMOSTRACIÓN COMPLETA](http://rextester.com/BBJN29297)**</kbd> de los datos usados en la respuesta.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Gracias amigo, problema resuelto